# How to get list of disconnected BLE while scanning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

Please check following code:

```
NSDictionary *scanOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:scanOptions];
```

I'm able to scan all the BLEs and connect successfully. I have a button in my app to scan again for BLEs. When I try to scan again using above code, it scans all the BLEs and disconnect all the BLEs which are already connected.

So is there any way to scan only for those Peripherals which are not connected.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NO,there isn't a way to scan only for the connected Peripherals.

As `- scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`  method is the only way to scan for Peripherals,You can scan only for the Peripherals with special services by specify the `services`  parameter.   Or you can specify `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` and `CBCentralManagerScanOptionSolicitedServiceUUIDsKey` in options parameter,both have nothing to do with connect state.

But you can discover all peripherals and pick out the disconnected peripherals by check the peripheral's `state` in callback:`- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI`

Comment: Thanks wj2061 for the reply .

Comment: I think you got my question wrong . Let me explain you guys what i want to achieve .I scan for the Peripherals and connected all the Peripherals successfully without any problem .
Problem :- I have scan button in my app , on pressing the i scan again for the Peripherals  so the Peripherals which are already connected got disconnected and  and come in`callback:- `didDiscoverPeripheral`.Now i am connecting it again. Is it right way of doing it ?

Comment: I don't understand why scanning again should disconnect the previous ones. There must be something wrong in your code or in your architecture. Do you keep reference for each CBPeripheral you connect to?